# Mock System class to get system properties

Tags: java, mocking, environment-variables, system, powermock

I have a folder path set in system variable through JVM arguments in Eclipse and I am trying to access it in my class as: 
`System.getProperty("my_files_path")`.

While writing junit test method for this class, I tried mocking this call as test classes do not consider JVM arguments. I have used PowerMockito to mock static System class and tried returning some path when `System.getProperpty` is being called.

Had `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` and `@PrepareForTest(System.class)` annotations at class level. However, System class is not getting mocked as a result I always get null result.
 Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 16):

Thanks Satish. This works except with a small modification. I wrote PrepareForTest(PathFinder.class), preparing the class I am testing for test cases instead of System.class

Also, as mock works only once, I called my method right after mocking. 
My code just for reference:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(PathInformation.class)
public class PathInformationTest {

    private PathFinder pathFinder = new PathFinder();

@Test
    public void testValidHTMLFilePath() { 
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(System.class);
        PowerMockito.when(System.getProperty("my_files_path")).thenReturn("abc");
        assertEquals("abc",pathFinder.getHtmlFolderPath());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

There are certain classes PowerMock can't mock in the usual way. See here:

- https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockSystem

This, however, may still not work. In order of "good design" preference, you can fall back to these:

1. **Refactor your code!** Using a System property for passing a file path around is probably not the best way. Why not use a properties file loaded into a Properties object? Why not use getters/setters for the components that need to know this path? There are many better ways to do this.

   The only reason I could think of *not* to do this is you're trying to wrap a test harness around code you "can't" modify.
2. Use `@Before` and `@After` methods to set the System property to some known value for the test(s). You could even make it part of the `@Test` method itself. This will be FAR easier than attempting to mock through PowerMock. Just call `System.setProperty("my_files_path","fake_path");`

Comment: What if I need to set different values to the property in each test? In this case, `@Before` and `@After` will not work, because only static values go there.

Comment: @WesternGun If you read the second sentence of the second list item, I mention "You could even make it part of the \@Test method itself."

Comment: OK missed that. My case is a little bit different and setting the property is not working. It's an in-house annotation which read the property from the injection point. At last I wrapped getting the property into a getter and mocked that in test.

Answer (score 7):

**System class is declared as final and cannot be mocked** by libraries such as PowerMock. Several answers posted here are incorrect. If you are using [Apache System Utils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/SystemUtils.html) you can use `getEnvironmentVariable` method instead of calling System.getenv directly. SystemUtils can be mocked since it is not declared as final.

Answer (score 5):

Set the system property in your test and ensure that it is restored after the test by using the rule [RestoreSystemProperties](http://stefanbirkner.github.io/system-rules/apidocs/org/junit/contrib/java/lang/system/RestoreSystemProperties.html) of the library [System Rules](http://stefanbirkner.github.io/system-rules/index.html).

```
public class PathInformationTest {
  private PathFinder pathFinder = new PathFinder();

  @Rule
  public TestRule restoreSystemProperties = new RestoreSystemProperties();

  @Test
  public void testValidHTMLFilePath() { 
    System.setProperty("my_files_path", "abc");
    assertEquals("abc",pathFinder.getHtmlFolderPath());
  }
}
```

Comment: Environment Variable (retrieved with `System.getenv`) is not the same thing as System Property (retrieved with `System.getProperty`).

Answer (score 2):

The System.setter or getter method should be put in a user defined method and that method can be mocked to return the desired property in unit test.

```
public String getSysEnv(){
return System.getEnv("thisprp");
}
```

Comment: It doesn't even need powermock. Simple mockito can mock above call and return the desired string.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that worked for me, was wrapping getting the property into a getter method and mock the getter in test. PowerMockito and others don't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

In the below code, mocking behaves as expected;

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(System.class)
public class MySuperClassTest {   
@Test
public void test(){ 
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(System.class);
    PowerMockito.when(System.getProperty("java.home")).thenReturn("abc");
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.home"));
}
}
```

But we use `System.getProperty("java.home")` in the real application logic not in  test method. I mean not as here `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.home"))`

So in the real application logic mocking didn't run well. So had to wrap `System.getProperty("java.home")` in a method and mock that method.

Answer (score -1):

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(System.class)
public class MySuperClassTest {   
@Test
public void test(){ 
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(System.class);
    PowerMockito.when(System.getProperty("java.home")).thenReturn("abc");
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.home"));
}
}
```

Comment: Will you please share the required dependencies to this code.

Answer (score -1):

Sailaja  add  System.class because as per the power mock guidelines for static,private mocking you should add the class in prepare for test.

```
 @PrepareForTest({PathInformation.class,System.class})
```

Hope this helps.let me know if it doesn't work